# SQL "in" type behaviour with a WCF Dataservice

Tags: wcf, linq, web-services, odata

Here's what I want to do :

```
string[] names= {"Dave","Mike","Sara","Roger"};
var events = eventsDB.where(a=>names.Contains(a.name));
```

I think that's pretty clear. Where eventsDB is a Linq to SQL connection, all is well - But this won't work with a service. Is there any way to achieve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tips guys, I think I've found a way to get what I want from the web service without having to add another method to the service by simply building the query URI manually ... partly.

```
string[] names = { "Dave", "Mike", "Sara", "Roger" };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("(");

foreach (string s in names)
{
    sb.Append(String.Format("name eq '{0}'",s));
    sb.Append(" or ");
}
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 4, 4);
sb.Append(")");

var events = eventsDB.AddQueryOption("$filter",sb.toString());
```

notice the AddQueryOption function

Answer (score 0):

You could expose a service method which returns an array.

Then you could call it like

```
serviceProxy.serviceMethod.where(....
```

But I don't think you would want to so this. For a start, a database and a service are completely different things.

Linq to WCF? Nice idea but does not compute.

Answer (score 0):

OData the underlying protocol for WCF Data Services currently doesn't support this.

You could implement a service operation to do this on the server side and pass in the list of values as a parameter. Note that for service operation the list would have to be concatenated to a single string, so for example comma separated list. If you would go with action instead you can pass in the list directly.

The other option is to construct a query similar to that. If the number of values in the array is small you can construct a query like
Where(a => a.Name == "John" || a.Name == "Mary" || ...)